# What does it mean to be a "variant type"?

Tags: c++

How would you define a variant type in C++? Is it the union itself or its members or what? I have tried to do some research on my own (of course), but did not find a clear answer.

Comment: `std::variant`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: I have read that, but did not really understand it (with regards to "a variant type")

Comment: Did you look at the examples (bottom of the link)?

Comment: @RichardCritten Well, I did see that, yes. I do understand like what semantically a variant type is, but cannot find a way to define it.

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question as it is becoming more unclear what you want to do.  If you are unable to use `std::variant` for some reason you should say so in the question.

Comment: @RichardCritten well, my question does not really have anything to do with std::variant. I am just looking for a specific definition of what a variant type is. Also, I have seen some examples, both in the link you provided and when looking at unions, but still, I cannot find a good definition of what a variant type it.

Comment: @asd So that's what it is. 'to define' has a special meaning in most programming languages, that's why the title is confusing.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I see... :(

Comment: @asd Well, if you're asking about `union` s, you should probably lookup [`union`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) first, rather than _variant type_??

Comment: @TheDude I do know what a union is, but not what a variant type is - that is the issue. So I am trying to find a definition of "variant types" because I keep encountering that phrase without knowing an actual definition. Could you explain what a "variant type" is?

Comment: @asd I have no clue what you're asking about. If `std::variant` doesn't answer your problem, and `union` doesn't either, you're probably chasing for unicorns.

Comment: Okay wait, let me show an example: take a look at this [article](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) - see the uses of "non-variant type"? What does that mean in this context? That is what I am trying to find a definition for. Can you help with that?

Comment: @TheDude they refer to a union when using this phrasing but is a "variant type" simply just a union or the members of it or what? Hope that you get me now.

Comment: @asd Well, regarding `std::variant` it may hold only one specific type with an instance. It doesn't use a `union` internally. In the context of the `constexpr` it means that everything must be initialized at compile time, and cannot change at runtime anymore.

Comment: @TheDude Ahh okay, thanks. And by saying that std::variant may only hold one specific type with an instance, does that also mean that a union with several members of different types cannot be used? I mean std::variant represents a **union** and thus if std::variant shall only hold one type, that must be the same as saying that a union shall only hold one type. Am I correct? Thank you so very much! You actually answered my primary wonder!!

Answer (score 1):

You define a variant like this:
`std::variant<int, float> x;`
So x can now either be an int or a float (it is after all by definition a typesafe union).

You can then assign it a value:
`x = 5;`
So x is now an integer with value 5. To retrieve the value use get, eg:
`int y = std::get<int>(x);`
Trying to retrieve an incorrect type yields an error.

I hope that is what you were asking.

Comment: *"well, my question does not really have anything to do with std::variant. I am just looking for a specific definition of what a variant type is"* It seems they just want a word definition.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you. Sad that Thantalos spent time answering something that I did not intend to ask and specified in the comments (+the edited title).